# Links not visible when loading json data dynamically into D3 Network Visualization

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, d3.js, visualization

I have a json file of nodes and then the links specified with source and target.

```
    {
    "links":[
        {"_id": "5a4b2866235fa755b6576903", "target": 6746, "source": 2169},
        {"_id": "5a4b2866235fa755b65768e3", "target": 6746, "source": 6357},
        {"_id": "5a4b2866235fa755b6576641", "target": 7045, "source": 8590}
            ],

    "nodes":[
        {"_id": "5a4b281e235fa755b6576340", "id": 6746, "Citation": "Chandler", "citedNo": "0", "size": 10},
        {"_id": "5a4b281d235fa755b657447f", "id": 1195, "Citation": "Aaron", "citedNo": "0", "size": 0},
        {"_id": "5a4b281e235fa755b657591f", "id": 4438, "Citation": "Chris", "citedNo": "0", "size": 10},
        {"_id": "5a4b281e235fa755b6575f31", "id": 7045, "Citation": "Brittany", "citedNo": "0", "size": 10},
        {"_id": "5a4b281e235fa755b6575f27", "id": 2169, "Citation": "James", "citedNo": "0", "size": 10},
        {"_id": "5a4b281e235fa755b6575ecb", "id": 6357, "Citation": "David", "citedNo": "0", "size": 10},
        {"_id": "5a4b281e235fa755b6575750", "id": 8590, "Citation": "Kris", "citedNo": "0", "size": 10}
            ]
    }
```

When I load the above data from within the file, the links show up. When I do this dynamically, no links are visible.

Why dynamically? The keyword is searched using ElasticSearch on MongoDB, there is a json created with nodes, links (sources and targets) and that is referenced in the js for creating the D3 network visualization.

I need to do this dynamically since the search use cases would be limitless and filtering and storing so many versions of json files would be sub-optimal.

Code for creating the arrays is below

```
    var arr = new Object;
    arr["nodes"] = nodearray;
    arr["links"] = linkarray;
```

Script for creating D3 network visualization is below

```
    d3.json('d3datap.json', function(error, graph) {
                      // console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
                      var graph = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr));
                      console.log(graph.nodes);
                      console.log(graph.links);
                      const width = 1200;
                      const height = 500;

                      const mouseOverFunction = function (d) {
                        const circle = d3.select(this);

                        node.append("text")
                        .attr("x", 12)
                        .attr("dy", ".35em")
                        .text(function(d) { return d.Party; });

                        node
                          .transition(500)
                            .style('opacity', o => {
                              const isConnectedValue = isConnected(o, d);
                              if (isConnectedValue) {
                                return 1.0;
                              }
                              return 0.2
                            })
                            .style('fill', (o) => {
                              let fillColor;
                              if (isConnectedAsTarget(o, d) && isConnectedAsSource(o, d)) {
                                fillColor = 'green';
                              } else if (isConnectedAsSource(o, d)) {
                                fillColor = 'red';
                              } else if (isConnectedAsTarget(o, d)) {
                                fillColor = 'blue';
                              } else if (isEqual(o, d)) {
                                fillColor = 'hotpink';
                              } else {
                                fillColor = '#000';
                              }
                              return fillColor;
                            });

                        link
                          .transition(500)
                            .style('stroke-opacity', o => (o.source === d || o.target === d ? 1 : 0.2))
                            .transition(500)
                            .attr('marker-end', o => (o.source === d || o.target === d ? 'url(#arrowhead)' : 'url()'));

                        circle
                          .transition(500)
                            .attr('r', () => 1.4 * nodeRadius(d));
                      };

                      const mouseOutFunction = function () {
                        const circle = d3.select(this);

                        svg.selectAll("text").remove();

                        node
                          .transition(500);

                        link
                          .transition(500);

                        circle
                          .transition(500)
                            .attr('r', nodeRadius);
                      };

                      const nodes = graph.nodes;
                      const links = graph.links;

                      const simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
                        .force('link', d3.forceLink().id(d => d.id))
                        .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody())
                        .force('center', d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

                        // const simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
                        //   .nodes(nodes)
                        // .links(links)
                        // .charge(-3000)
                        // .friction(0.6)
                        // .gravity(0.6)
                        // .size([width, height])
                        // .start();

                      const svg = d3.select('#vis').append('svg')
                        .attr('width', width)
                        .attr('height', height)
                        .classed("svg-content", true);

                      let link = svg.selectAll('line')
                        .data(graph.links)
                        .enter().append('line');

                      let node = svg.selectAll('.node')
                        .data(graph.nodes)
                        .enter().append("g")
                          .attr('class', 'node');

                      node.append("svg:a")
                        .append('circle')
                          .attr("r", nodeRadius)
                          .on('mouseover', mouseOverFunction)
                          .on('mouseout', mouseOutFunction)
                          .call(d3.drag()
                            .on("start", dragstarted)
                            .on("drag", dragged)
                            .on("end", dragended))
                          .on("dblclick",function(d){
                              window.open(d.url, '_blank')});



                      svg
                        .append('marker')
                        .attr('id', 'arrowhead')
                        .attr('refX', 6 + 7) // Controls the shift of the arrow head along the path
                        .attr('refY', 2)
                        .attr('markerWidth', 6)
                        .attr('markerHeight', 4)
                        .attr('orient', 'auto')
                        .append('path')
                          .attr('d', 'M 0,0 V 4 L6,2 Z');

                      link
                        .attr('marker-end', 'url()');

                      simulation
                        .nodes(graph.nodes)
                        .on('tick', ticked);

                      simulation.force('link')
                        .links(graph.links);

                      let linkedByIndex = {};
                      links.forEach((d) => {
                        linkedByIndex[`${d.source.index},${d.target.index}`] = true;
                      });

                      function isConnected(a, b) {
                        return isConnectedAsTarget(a, b) || isConnectedAsSource(a, b) || a.index === b.index;
                      }

                      function isConnectedAsSource(a, b) {
                        return linkedByIndex[`${a.index},${b.index}`];
                      }

                      function isConnectedAsTarget(a, b) {
                        return linkedByIndex[`${b.index},${a.index}`];
                      }

                      function isEqual(a, b) {
                        return a.index === b.index;
                      }

                      function ticked() {
                        link
                          .attr('x1', d => d.source.x)
                          .attr('y1', d => d.source.y)
                          .attr('x2', d => d.target.x)
                          .attr('y2', d => d.target.y);

                        node
                          .attr('transform', d => `translate(${d.x},${d.y})`);
                        }

                      function nodeRadius(d) { return Math.pow(40.0 * d.size, 1 / 3); }

                      function dragstarted(d) {
                        if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
                        d.fx = d.x;
                        d.fy = d.y;
                      }

                      function dragged(d) {
                        d.fx = d3.event.x;
                        d.fy = d3.event.y;
                      }

                      function dragended(d) {
                        if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
                        d.fx = null;
                        d.fy = null;
                      }
                      });
```

CSS is below

```
    .node circle {
          stroke: white;
          stroke-width: 1.5px;
          opacity: 1.0;
        }

        line {
          stroke: black;
          stroke-width: 1.5px;
          stroke-opacity: 1.0;
        }
```

I can see the data for the json in the console but the links are not visible/ not there. I searched all the questions on dynamic loading of json into D3 but couldn't find a solution to my problem. If anyone can point out what is the problem with this, I'd appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 1):

d3.json is an asynchronous call. You appear to be creating the `arr` object somewhere above your json call:

```
d3.json('d3datap.json', function(error, graph) {
       // graph is passed in, but arr is used??
                  // console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
                  var graph = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

Therefore the `arr` object may or may not be fully formed when d3 is using it.  When you `console.log` the graph, chrome updates that object after the asynchronous call completes, so it may appear that it contains all of the data when you look at it, but d3 isn't getting the data.  Your code should use the `graph` value that you're getting from the `d3.json` call.

If you post additional code about your `arr` generation and why it's up above your `d3.json` call then I can update this answer.  In general, it's better to post your entire code block rather than posting bits of it (and it's best to provide a link to a bl.ocks.org or blockbuilder.org or  codepen version of the code).

Comment: Yes as per your advise, I've modularized the code and also added the d3-queue to make it work. However, now receiving an "Invalid Callback" error.